# MYSQL sum of a field depending on the value of other field

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to create a field as

1.sum the purchases field where value of purchases type=vat as purchases_vat

2.sum the purchase field where value of purchase type=exempt as purchases_exempt

source table & result table example in attached image

[example table](http://mywebsolutions.co.in/images/purchase.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases_type='vat' THEN Purchases ELSE 0 END) AS purchases_vat,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases_type='exempt' THEN Purchases ELSE 0 END) AS purchases_exempt,
```

Answer (score 0):

Two row version:

```
SELECT 'vat', SUM(purchases)
FROM source_table
WHERE purchase_type = 'vat4'

UNION

SELECT 'exempt', SUM(purchases)
FROM source_table
WHERE purchase_type = 'exempt';
```

One row:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT sum(purchases) from source_table where purchase_type = 'vat4') purchase_vat,
    (SELECT sum(purchases) from source_table where purchase_type = 'exempt') purchase_exempt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the sum of purchases for 'vat'. You can similarly do this for 'exempt'

```
SELECT `s` FROM (SELECT SUM(purchases), type FROM my_table GROUP BY type) as T1 WHERE T1.type = 'vat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    sum(case when purchase_type = 'vat4' then purchases else 0 end) as purchase_vat4,
    sum(case when purchase_type = 'exempt' then purchases else 0 end) as purchase_exempt
from source_table
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've tested yours version and mine in SQL Server and mine is faster (twice). You are executing two queries one sums values for `vat4` and other one sums `exempt` so in my opinion it's not efficient.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you are trying to say that I can omit words `from source_table` - in my opinion it's impossible, because how could you (or MySQL) know where are `purchase_type` and `purchases` columns? If you are talking about keyword `from` only then according to [12.2.8. SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) it isn't possible as well (part: `[FROM table_references`). Buuuuut I can't test it right now and maybe I don't know about something. All I know it won't work without `from` in this form (I've used) in SQL Server.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Never mind. I was somehow thinking that it's my code :-)